# Winsock socket receives one packet per launch

Tags: c++, winsock2

When I launch the following code, the raw socket picks up a packet. However, each subsequent call of the recvfrom() on this socket gets the exact same packet.

```
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
int err;

wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
if (err != 0) {
    std::cout << "Usable Winsock2 not found." << std::endl;
    return 22;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Initialized Winsock2.\n";
}

SOCKET listenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
if (listenSock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    std::cout << "Failed socket creation. Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Created socket.\n";
}

int socketOptionToSet = 1;
int socketOptionSetResult = setsockopt(listenSock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char*)&socketOptionToSet, sizeof(int));
if (socketOptionSetResult) {
    std::cout << "Unable to set socket option. Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Set socket option.\n";
}

sockaddr_in service;
service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(/*My local IP*/);
service.sin_port = htons(0);
memset(&(service.sin_zero), 0, 8);

int sockBindResult = bind(listenSock, (sockaddr *) &service, sizeof(service));
if (sockBindResult) {
    std::cout << "Unable to bind socket. Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Bound socket.\n";
}

int inBuffer = 1;
DWORD receivedByteSize;
int socketModeResult = WSAIoctl(listenSock, SIO_RCVALL, &inBuffer, sizeof(inBuffer), 0, 0, &receivedByteSize, 0, 0);
if (socketModeResult) {
    std::cout << "Unable to set socket mode. Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Set socket mode.\n";
}


char* socketBuffer = (char*)malloc(SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX);
memset(socketBuffer, 0, SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX);
if (!socketBuffer) {
    std::cout << "No buffer space." << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Created receiver buffer.\n";
}


bool stop = false;

int receiveResult = 1;

int latest = -1;
int prev = -1;

while (receiveResult > 0) {
    receiveResult = recvfrom(listenSock, socketBuffer, SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX, MSG_PEEK, 0, 0);
    if (receiveResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", receiveResult);
        prev = latest;
        latest = parseAndPrintSniffedPacket(socketBuffer, receiveResult);
        memset(socketBuffer, 0, SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX);
    }
    else if (receiveResult == 0) {
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("recv failed. Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
}
```

The buffer *does* get replaced in its entirety; I tried freeing and allocating it every cycle, but it didn't help.

The packet gets picked up on a per-socket basis; I tried creating a new socket whenever a duplicate packet was received, in which case each new socket received a different packet and continued to receive that same packet. It crashed pretty quickly (probably because I didn't close the old sockets in any way), and seems like a terrible idea in general, so I didn't continue down that path.

Includes are:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <mstcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: You pass `MSG_PEEK` to `recvfrom`. This means "get the bytes but don't remove them from receive queue, so they could be read again". You get exactly what you ask for.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you! That was indeed the problem.